# Change permissions of file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have code as follows

```
 def initialise
   @doc_path =nil
   @user= nil
end
def execute
   oscmd = Common::OsCmd.new
   oscmd.log = @log.info("message")
   File.open("#{@doc_path}/new.doc","w") do |f|
      f.puts "/#{@name}  /people/* "
      File.chmod(0777,"#{@doc_path}/new.doc")
      FileUtils.chown("#{@user}, #{@user}, #{@doc_path}")
   end
end
```

So my code gets executed by tokenisation from other config file where it has values for `doc_path`, `user`

My code is giving error on `chown` and `chmod`

Comment: why does the "doc" to be executable?

Comment: if i comment out chmod and chown lines.. the code works well.. it creates the doc and populate the file.

Comment: Does the User that the script runs, has the rights to chown and chmod? (root or special file permissions)

Comment: In this line `FileUtils.chown(#{@user}, #{@user}, "#{@doc_path}")`, you missed `".."` also

Comment: where i missed this ".."

Comment: Let's take care of problems one by one. Comment FileUtils first and see what error messages say. And then comment File and uncomment FileUtils and see the results. When the code is broken and no error/log message is available, it's just very hard to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the below by passing valid user in chown :

```
def self.execute
   oscmd = Common::OsCmd.new
   oscmd.log = @log.info("message")
   File.open("#{@doc_path}/new.doc","w") do |f|
      f.puts "/#{@name}  /people/* "
      File.chmod(0777,"#{@doc_path}/new.doc")
      FileUtils.chown 'vinod', 'vinod', "#{@doc_path}" 
   end #-- do ends here
end #-- def ends here
```

chown usage:

http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/chown